# Looking for exact name of Grass weeds

Tags: lawn, weeds

Hello I am working on grass weed detection. I have captured three different types of weeds from my Univ lawn. But I want to know the name of those weeds.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Aadnan! We prefer one plant per question to avoid multiple partial answers that will make the topic a little bit tangled to follow. However, your plants look somewhat common, so other members might consider answering. I suggest that you split your question by keeping the plantago here since you have an answer for it, and asking new questions for the other plants. Please read this explanation: https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/for-identification-please-only-post-one-plant-per-question

Comment: And the region/continent helps. Many weeds are continent specific. (on specific level)

Comment: Its in Australia

Answer (score 3):

Plant B looks like a [Plantago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantago), possibly the common one as seen in this article: [Herb Plantago Major or Common Plantain and  its Medicinal Uses](https://chingchailah.blogspot.com/2015/02/herb-plantago-major-or-common-plantain.html).

Comment: The comments are deleted??